# Python inheritance questions

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, parent-child

I'm a self-taught programmer and currently I'm learning elementary python; read material with inheritance in python yet still don't understand how it works.

Here, players is a child class of Football; however, it can't inherit the function/ objects (.getCoach) from Football. (error: p.getCoach())- the final line.
May I know which part goes wrong?

```
class Football:
    def __init__(self, name, ranking, coach):
        self.name= name
        self.rank = ranking
        self.coach= coach
    def getName(self):
        print(self.name)
    def getRank(self):
        print(self.name+ "was in" + self.rank)
    def getCoach(self):
        if self.rank<5:
            print(self.coach+ "is a bad coach")
        else:
            print(self.coach+ "is a good coach")

class Players(Football):
    def __init__(self, Appearances, Score):
        self.Appearances= Appearances
        self.Score= Score
    def getapp(self):
        print(self.Appearances)
    def getscore(self):
        print(self.Score)

p = Players(5,5, "Vincent")
p.getCoach()
```

Comment: FWIW, that class hierarchy and/or naming doesn't make sense. *Is* a player *a* football? No. `class Player(Person)` or `class Defence(Player)` makes sense, `class Players(Football)` doesn't really. Also, a class should be singlular, `Player`, not `Players`.

Comment: This also doesn't run. p throws an error.

Comment: You should also add the full error message.

Comment: I get an obvious error because you gave 3 values to `Players` initialization, but that initialization takes only two.  I don't see any error regarding inheritance.

Comment: @prune, Shd I add one more attribute as the coach in player __init___.

Comment: How are you planning to initialize coach and rank in parent class?

Comment: `Football` (which would be better named `Team`) could have keep a list of players on the team as an attribute, and a `Player` attribute could store a reference to the team the player (currently) plays for. There is no relationship between the two that would be modeled by inheritance.

Comment: @prune, apart from that, what should I add?

Comment: Is your code really indented as shown in the question? Because if that's the case the methods don't belong to the classes. Also the attributes of the parent class will not appear in child class if you don't call the parent function with `super`. Also read about naming conventions in the PEP8 please.

Comment: I can't tell you what to add, because you haven't described how you intend these interfaces to operate.  If you want help sorting out the implementation, we'll need you to clarify the design.

Comment: Hi guys...these are only the examples I created. Wanna understand a bit abt the syntax first

Comment: @vincentshiusun You need to learn what inheritance is, how it works, and what it is meant to represent before you should worry about Python's particular syntax for it.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the topic, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

You called `Players` with the arguments to Football's `__init__` method, yet your `Players.__init__` doesn't call `Football.__init__`.  And it appears you want to pass two additional values when initializing a `Player`.

The following uses `super` to call the parent's `__init__` function.  Note that `Player.__init__` needs to take all of the parameters needed for `Football.__init__`, unless you have some other way of coming up with them.  It lets the `Football` class initialize the fields it cares about (via `super()`), then `Player` initializes its own fields.  Note that this code assumes Python 3 because it calls `super()` with no arguments; the syntax for Python 2 is a bit different.

```
class Football:
    def __init__(self, name, ranking, coach):
        self.name= name
        self.rank = ranking
        self.coach= coach
    def getName(self):
        print(self.name)
    def getRank(self):
        print(self.name+ "was in" + self.rank)
    def getCoach(self):
        if self.rank<5:
            print(self.coach+ "is a bad coach")
        else:
            print(self.coach+ "is a good coach")

class Players(Football):
    def __init__(self, name, ranking, coach, Appearances, Score):
        super().__init__(name, ranking, coach)      # calls Football.__init__()
        self.Appearances= Appearances
        self.Score= Score
    def getapp(self):
        print(self.Appearances)
    def getscore(self):
        print(self.Score)

p = Players(5,5, "Vincent", 2, 3)
p.getCoach()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of issues here. First.

- relationship does not make sense.
- parent class is not derived from `object` class so inheritance will not work.  (alteast in 2.7)
- it seems like your player class contains information about Coach and not actual player. and so it doesn't make any sense. if you want to store information about Coach. Create a `Has-A relationship`. in simpler terms create a separate class named `Coach` and instantiate it inside the class **Footballer**. or **player**.
- I would suggest to go through PEP8 standards.

However not addressing other issue, just to see what's wrong with the code. 
This might work.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, ranking, coach):
        self.name= name
        self.rank = ranking
        self.coach= coach

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def get_rank(self):
        print(self.name + "was in" + self.rank)

    def get_coach(self):
        if self.rank<5:
            print(self.coach + "is a bad coach")
        else:
            print(self.coach + "is a good coach")


class Footballer(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, ranking, coach, appearances, score):
        self.appearances= appearances
        self.score= score
        super(Footballer, self).__init__(name, ranking, coach)

    def get_appearances(self):
        print(self.Appearances)

    def get_score(self):
        print(self.Score)


p = Footballer("name", 20.2, "coach name", "appearances", 200)
p.get_coach()
```

Here you can say, a Footballer is a player.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Self-learnt from scratch is a bit hard, especially for a guy who didnt study computer science before.

Comment: My tutorial taught me on Class Child(parent) then it will inherit all parent function. But not a word on Super function- seems youtube tutorial is bad